# TensorRT + PyInstaller on Nvidia Jetson Nano. Deserialize engine causes Cuda Error in loadKernel: 3 (initialization error)

Tags: pyinstaller, pycuda, tensorrt, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have a code reading a serialized `TensorRT` engine:

```
import tensorrt as trt
import pycuda.driver as cuda

cuda.init()
device = cuda.Device(0)
context = device.make_context()
logger = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.INFO)
with trt.Runtime(logger) as runtime:
    with open('model.trt', 'rb') as in_:
        engine = runtime.deserialize_cuda_engine(in_.read())
```

which runs just fine on my Nvidia Jeston Nano, until I compile it with `Pyinstaller`

```
pyinstaller temp.py
```

In the compiled code `runtime.deserialize_cuda_engine` returns None and logger says:

```
Cuda Error in loadKernel: 3 (initialization error)
[TensorRT] ERROR: INVALID_STATE: std::exception
[TensorRT] ERROR: INVALID_CONFIG: Deserialize the cuda engine failed.
```

When I construct the engine from scratch, like

```
cuda.init()
device = cuda.Device(0)
context = device.make_context()
logger = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.INFO)
with ExitStack() as stack:
    builder = stack.enter_context(trt.Builder(logger))
    network = stack.enter_context(builder.create_network(
        1 << int(trt.NetworkDefinitionCreationFlag.EXPLICIT_BATCH)
    ))

    i = network.add_input('input0', trt.float16, (3, 2))
    s = network.add_softmax(i)
    network.mark_output(s.get_output(0))
    config = stack.enter_context(builder.create_builder_config())
    ...some builder settings like opt profiles and fp16 mode...
    engine = builder.build_engine(network, config)
```

then everything works fine, even after compilation.

The engine was prepared with `trtexec` on the same computer. `Cuda` version is `V10.2.89`, `pycuda` version is `2019.1.2`. I believe it's a standard jetson installation as of August 2020.

Any ideas what might be involved here and what workarounds might be?

Comment: Can you specify your `cuda` and `pycuda` versions?

Comment: @mibrahimy Cuda is V10.2.89, pycuda is 2019.1.2. I believe it's a standard jetson installation as of August 2020.

Comment: I have got same similar problem that cuda engine is working in normal python environment and not working with pyinstaller. i suspect that it is problem with pycuda in freeze environment. As a work around i just excluded cuda package while building the  installation package(--exclude-module=pycuda) with pyinstaller and copied entire Pycuda folder from python packages. It worked for me.